# avoid loading the images for the first time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a html page with 12 images and 12 different modal pop ups opening with each click respectively and different images in each.
The problem is when I load the html page all the images in the 12 pop ups are loaded for the first time which makes the site slow.
Each pop contains a carousel.

I tried lazy load but it does not work for the images inside the modal.
I also tried appending the images through jquery.append put the images in the carousel work only for single pop up, though I have passed it with different id.

Following is my html code with jquery for single pop .

Here is the single image

```
<div id="profile-item-bfc" class="our-work-img-thumb col-lg-2" > 
        <div class="profile-item-detail" > <img src="../img/portfolio/thumb/bfc.png" alt="Big Funny Cards" >
          <h5 > Big Funny Cards </h5>
        </div> 
      </div>
```

Here is the pop up on click without jquery append

```
 <div id="profile-div-bfc" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog apps-detail">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4" >
              <div id="myCarousel_bfc" class="carousel slide apps-detail-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel_bfc" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel_bfc" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel_bfc" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                   <li data-target="#myCarousel_bfc" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel_bfc" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div id="bfc-inner"  class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="item active"> <img src="../img/portfolio/full/bfc/bfc_screen1.jpg"  > </div>
                  <div class="item"> <img src="../img/portfolio/full/bfc/bfc_screen2.jpg" > </div>
                 <div class="item"> <img src="../img/portfolio/full/bfc/bfc_screen3.jpg" > </div>


                </div>
                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel_bfc" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel_bfc" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span  class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the pop up with jquery append

```
 <div id="profile-div-bfc" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog apps-detail">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4" >
              <div id="myCarousel_bfc" class="carousel slide apps-detail-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel_bfc" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel_bfc" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel_bfc" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                   <li data-target="#myCarousel_bfc" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel_bfc" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div id="bfc-inner"  class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                </div>
                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel_bfc" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel_bfc" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span  class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Jquery code

```
$('#profile-item-bfc').on('click',function(){
                $('#bfc-inner').append('<div class="item active"> <img src="../img/portfolio/full/bfc/bfc_screen1.jpg"> </div>');
                $('#bfc-inner').append('<div class="item"> <img src="../img/portfolio/full/bfc/bfc_screen2.jpg"> </div>' );
                $('#bfc-inner').append('<div class="item"> <img src="../img/portfolio/full/bfc/bfc_screen3.jpg"> </div>' );


            $("#profile-div-bfc").modal("show");
            $('body').addClass('body-scroll');
    })
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can append each image after you clicked each button. but for get any solution we need see your codes. so please add it!

Comment: you don't want to load images or just doesn't want to show?

Comment: This article could be of your interest: http://seandebutts.com/2013/07/03/html5-delay-loading-images-iframes/

Comment: What do you mean by "jquery.append put the images in the carousel work only for single pop up, though I have passed it with different id"?

Comment: @alexanderbird :  If I use the append code as shown above for all the pop ups , the carousel does not work properly , this may be due to the class active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to load the images with JavaScript after the page loads

## 1. Have html containers for the images, and leave them empty

```
<div id="firstPopup"><!-- placeholder --></div>
```

## 2. On [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) the images:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#firstPopup").load("/your_image_content_path.html");
    /* for each popup, do the same */
  });
</script>
```

## 3. Put your popup html at that path

so browsing to `/your_image_content_path.html` shows

```
<div class="popup"><img src="stuff.img"><p>Other content</p></div>
```

Comment: Your this solution has solved my problem for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while ago, this is what I did:
I load only a "loading" image which I load on all the pop ups (it'll be loaded once over the network and the other `img` will load the cached version)

```
<img src="loading.gif" id="loading" />
```

then when I open a popup:

```
popup.on('open', function () {
    var popup = $(this);
    if ($(popup).data('loaded')) {
       return;
    } else {
    //<div data-image-path="..." ></div>
    var imgPath = $(popup).data('image-path'); 
    var img = $('img');
    $(img).on('load', function() {
      //hide loading, then
      popup.append(this);
    });
    $(img).attr('src', imgPath);
    $(popup).data('loaded', true);
  }
});
```

That should do it.

PS: don't forget to hide the loading image (using css or just removing it from the DOM). Good luck.

Comment: This would only start loading the image when the popup is shown, wouldn't it? It seems like the image should be loaded as soon as possible after the document is loaded.

Comment: yeah but he said "I tried lazy load but it does not work for the images inside the modal. I also tried appending the images through jquery.append put the images in the carousel work only for single pop up, though I have passed it with different id."   so loading the images on popup:open is definitely a solution for him already.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the GibboK article the best approach is to use `data-original-src` attribute and have the real image stored there . The real `src` could be empty or leading to a `loading.gif` anim . Then upon showing the modal simply swap the fake `src` with the original.

### Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/qomokep/edit?html,output)

The modal `img` tag

```
    <img src="loader2.gif"
         data-original-src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"
         alt="">
```

The javascript to swap the `src`

```
  $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
     src = $(this).find('img').attr('data-original-src');
     $(this).find('img').attr('src', src);
   });
```

Comment: You can also use transparent base64 encoded image instead of a file : src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs="

Comment: I like the data-original-src idea. Though, as I commented on @FabriceKabongon's answer, doesn't this delay loading the image until the modal is shown? Wouldn't it be better to load it as soon as possible after the full document is loaded?

Comment: I think your solution would be better if you swapped the source on document ready rather than when the modal is shown

Comment: Agreed. With unlimited internet I'd rather have things preloaded so I don't have to wait half an extra second per click. It really depends on the behavior of the users tho. If on average only 2-3 modals are getting opened there is no point to waste that bandwidth. If 10-12 then preload on  pagelaod.